# Grunt - mongoimpot --headerlines?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, gruntjs

I am trying to upload a CSV file using the mongoimport plugin for grunt. I am receiving the following error when running `grunt`:

```
Running "mongoimport" task
2017-03-29T18:43:57.463-0700    error validating settings: must specify --fields, --fieldFile or --headerline to import th
is file type
2017-03-29T18:43:57.464-0700    try 'mongoimport --help' for more information
```

The error message is pretty obvious so I adjusted my grunt task to include `headerline: true`

This doesn't appear to be correct as the error remains the same. After looking at their documentation for any mentioning of the --headerline property, the only thing I see is this:

collection.fields

*Specify a comma separated list of field names when importing csv or tsv files that do not have field names in the first (i.e. header) line of the file.*
- https://github.com/andrewkeig/grunt-mongoimport

What is the correct way using grunt to import mongodb data from a csv?

gruntfile.ts

```
module.exports = (grunt) => {

  grunt.initConfig({

    mongoimport: {
      options: {
        db: 'mynewdatabase',
        collections: [
          {
            name: 'somethings',
            type: 'csv',
            file: 'data/test.csv',
            headerline: true // <----does not work
          }
        ]
      }
    }


  });

  //Load Plugins
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-mongoimport');


  //Run Tasks
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['mongoimport']);

}
```

The csv file does have headlines and if I run the below mongo command in a terminal, it works fine:

```
use mynewdatabase
mongoimport --db mynewdatabase --collection somethings --type csv --headerline --file test.csv
```

Looking at the mongimport source code, they have the following logic:

```
if (collection.type === 'csv' || collection.type === 'tsv') {
        if (collection.headerLine) args.push('--headerline');
    }
```

If i'm passing the type of `csv` then it looks like `--hearline` should be getting added already so the error message doesn't seem to be aligning with what i'm seeing the code/task...

Answer (score 0):

I was looking over the documentation. In their source code they have the following

```
if (collection.type === 'csv' || collection.type === 'tsv') {
        if (collection.headerLine) args.push('--headerline');
}
```

This means if you pass `headerLine: true` and your `type: 'csv'` then you mongoimport will include the `--headerline`

```
module.exports = (grunt) => {

  grunt.initConfig({

    mongoimport: {
      options: {
        db: 'mynewdatabase',
        collections: [
          {
            name: 'somethings',
            type: 'csv',
            file: 'data/test.csv',
            headerLine: true // <----works
          }
        ]
      }
    }


  });

  //Load Plugins
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-mongoimport');


  //Run Tasks
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['mongoimport']);

}
```